# Can we use Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE for older versions of Android API levels using Android Support Library?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

According to [`Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE) documentation:

> Used to indicate that a ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent can allow the user
>   to select and return multiple items. This is a boolean extra; the
>   default is false. If true, an implementation of ACTION_GET_CONTENT is
>   allowed to present the user with a UI where they can pick multiple
>   items that are all returned to the caller. When this happens, they
>   should be returned as the getClipData() part of the result Intent.

So we can use it as:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true).setType("image/*");
```

But this is available for Android API 18+ only.

So my question is can we use it for older versions of Android API levels using Android Support Library?

If yes, How?

Comment: Do you need this extra for an internal or external activity? For an external component like Gallery you're out of luck. But if it is for your own app then you probably can create a similar protocol as EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE.  Notice that the documentation refers to ClipData that was introduced earliern (11, some additions in api level 16). Depending on your minimum API level you might be able to implement multi selection with it. Another alternative is a custom protocol based on parcelable array/lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can we use it for older versions of Android API levels using Android
>   Support Library?

No, we can't, `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is not included in the Android Support Library, at least at this moment.

Comment: You should give more detail about why @iKrshnan can not use that Intent. This is an insufficient answer

Comment: @andy Great :(
If someone find answer for this, please add it here.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear. We can not use that Intent on older versions because it is not included in the android support library. You may check this by adding the latest release of android support to your project.

Comment: The reason is that the intent extra wouldn't have any effect. The Gallery would need to support receiving that intent, but older versions of the Gallery do not. You can still include it, and then only invoke it after a version check. It just won't work for anything below API 18.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can not use it before API 16. Because to use this you will be required to call [getClipData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getClipData%28%29) to get multiple paths/URIs, `getClipData` was added in API 16. But its better to use from API 18.